# How can I add a refresh button inside the webchat in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, frontend, botframework

I want to add a refresh button inside the webchat in Microsoft Bot Framework which will refresh the chat done till time and will start a new chat from root dialog. **Is it possible?** I am using Node.js in the back-end.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvoAq.png) image is the published bot's webchat.

And what I want is: 
 
I want to add a refresh button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7WuG.png) in the webchat, like the emulator has. Functionality of which is to clear the current conversation data and start it from the beginning.

Comment: I don't know who gave a thumbs down, may be my question is unclear to you! Adding some screenshots of the problem might help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to customize the WebChat control to provide this behavior.  It is open source, and can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eric :)